Ensuring Automatic Reconnection for Twilio Media Stream with OpenAI API After Temporary Network Loss
I'm building an AI Assistant using OpenAI's Realtime API and Twilio Media Stream, similar to this example by Twilio.
Due to specific requirements, I need to make the system as resilient as possible. One critical feature I need is automatic reconnection if the connection is lost temporarily (e.g., for a few seconds).
In theory, the WebSocket protocol should support reconnection within a specified timeout period. However, this isn't what I am experiencing. Here's what happens during my test:

I run the application on my laptop and place a call to the Twilio number from my phone.

During the call, I disable my laptop's WiFi for 2 seconds and then re-enable it.

I expect the connection to automatically recover within this short interruption period.


However, after reconnecting the WiFi, Twilio neither sends nor receives any data, and it terminates the call and connection after a few seconds.
I have also tried reopening the WebSocket connection from the server side once the network is restored, but Twilio does not respond to this attempt either.
I am looking for a solution that allows the connection to be restored automatically if the disruption occurs within a set timeout period. Any guidance or strategies to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
